# Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, cypress

I am trying to check the value from the Custom Error Text on the Ui. And once the condition gets failed I am capturing the screenshot.

But due to the Cypress Error, the screenshot code is not getting triggered. Is there any alternative way to achieve a similar task or fix the Cypress Error issue?

```
 Cypress.on("fail", (err, runnable) => {
            console.log("invalid", err);
            cy.get("#form-customer-mobile").screenshot("login/customer-pan-pattern-entered");
            return false;
        });


      cy.get(".error-text").invoke("text").should("contain", "Please enter a valid dasd PAN card number");
```

> invoke.text()
>
> assert expected Please enter a valid PAN card
> number to include Please enter a valid dasd PAN card number
> CypressError
>
> Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a
> command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.
>
> The command that returned the promise was:
>
> > cy.invoke()
>
> The cy command you invoked inside the promise was:
>
> > cy.get()
>
> Because Cypress commands are already promise-like, you don't need to
> wrap them or return your own promise.
>
> Cypress will resolve your command with whatever the final Cypress
> command yields.
>
> The reason this is an error instead of a warning is because Cypress
> internally queues commands serially whereas Promises execute as soon
> as they are invoked. Attempting to reconcile this would prevent
> Cypress from ever resolving.Learn more

Comment: You cannot use cypress commands within callback function for Cypress.on()